# Understanding fermion doubling in lattice QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

I'm studying Rothe's book on lattice gauge theory. For the case of a scalar field, we can use lattice discretization to find (using equations 3.18 and 3.19 on page 41)

$$\langle 0|T\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle=\int_{-\pi/a}^{\pi/a}\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{ik\cdot(x-y)}}{\sum_\mu \tilde{k}_\mu^2+M^2}$$ where $\tilde{k}_\mu$ is given by $$\tag{3.19b} \tilde{k}_\mu=\frac{2}{a}\sin \frac{k_\mu a}{2}$$

Presumably, as $a\rightarrow 0$, the integral converges to the well known $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{ik\cdot(x-y)}}{k^2+M^2}$.

On page 46, we have the similarly calculated, $$\tag{4.7a}\langle0|T\psi_\alpha(x)\overline{\psi}_\beta(y)0\rangle=\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\int_{-\pi/a}^{\pi/a}\frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{[-i\sum\gamma_\mu\tilde{p}_\mu+M]_{\alpha\beta}}{\sum_\mu\tilde{p}_\mu^2M^2}e^{ip\cdot(x-y)}$$ where $\tilde{p}_\mu$ is given by $$\tilde{p}_\mu=\frac{1}{a}\sin(p_\mu a).$$

The book says the second calculation suffers from the fermion doubling problem. However I don't see why there is a problem here. If (4.7a) does converge to the usual propogator just like the case of (3.19b), then what's wrong with it? Maybe the limit 4.7a simply doesn't exist(mathematically) because if $k$ is near $\pi/a$, then $\tilde{p}_\mu$ is roughly 0?

$\textbf{Edit:}$ I later realized that section 4.2(iii) (page 52) answers my question. In deed the original expression (4.7a) does not converge.